# Can I run and debug an application in compatibility mode for a different OS

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I would like to debug my application while the exe is running in compatibility mode for an older operating system.

Is there a built in way in Visual Studio to do this?

Comment: Do you mean compatibility mode?

Comment: You could try adding an infinite loop based on a variable to the beginning of the program, run it from a shortcut with the particular compatibility mode set, attach the debugger, break inside the loop, and change the variable so the loop ends and the program continues under the debugger.

Comment: Yeah but is there anyway built into VS?